# How to increase the lookup value by 1 row after I drag down the formula 23 rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

hope you guys can help. I have an old table from which I need to build a database. As you see, "Position 1" needs to be repeated 3 times, and then to move on with "Position" 2 of "Source A" another 3 times. Is there a formula where I can do this while referencing the old dataset?

[image]

Comment: "As you can see..." No, I can't I'm afraid. I can see two datasets but have no idea how they relate to one another. The new one just seems to be a repeating pattern of 3 1s and 2s for each letter, with no relationship to the old data. You probably need to explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve, the logic involved, possibly with an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to basically repeat every row 3 times before continuing on to the next row.

Lets say your data begins in row 4 like in your example. So, starting in F4

```
=INT((ROW()-ROW($F$4))/3)
```

Will return in F4:F100 = {0;0;0;1;1;1;2;2;2;3;3;3...}

Now all that is left to do is use that as an index into column B:

```
=INDEX($B$4:$B$1000, INT((ROW()-ROW($F$4))/3) + 1)
```